# SQL Select conditional IS NULL / IS NOT NULL from variable

Tags: sql-server, select, isnull

I am trying to design a SELECT statement, which can select rows where a column is NULL or NOT NULL depending on a variable.

I hope this explains it better:

```
DECLARE @var bit = 1;
IF (@var = 1)
  SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name> IS NULL
ELSE
  SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name> IS NOT NULL
GO
```

I would like to simplify this into one select, if possible.

Following is pseudo-code:

```
SELECT * FROM <table_name> WHERE <column_name> IS @nullNotNullVar
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @var bit = 1;

SELECT * 
FROM  <table_name> 
WHERE (@Var = 1 and <column_name> IS NULL)
  OR  (@Var = 0 and <column_name> IS NOT NULL)
```